# Problem with js with keypress enter dont send text

Tags: javascript

hello everyone sorry for the trouble got this issue with keypress, im trying to make a web chat and when a press enter the text is still in the textbox but when i click in the button it sends the message and dont erase it from the textbox heres my code:

```
       $("#txtmessage").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                $('#btnSendMsg').click();
            }
        });


        $('#btnSendMsg').click(function () {

            var msg = $("#txtmessage").val();
            if (msg.length > 0) {

                var userName = $('#hdUserName').val();

                var date = GetCurrentDateTime(new Date());

                chatHub.server.sendMessageToAll(userName, msg, date);
                $("#txtmessage").val('');


            }
        });
```

Comment: what `var keycode` and `console.log()` for? try the keydown event for enter keys.

Comment: `the text is still in the textbox` - is the message sent? Also, is there any error in the `console`?

Comment: console.log() dont send any value when i press enter i put console.log to see if it show anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has to be an issue with HTML likely your element id that is being used does not match the actual element id in the page. Code works, see below:

```js
const chatHub = {
         server: {
           sendMessageToAll: function(userName, msg) { 
            console.log(arguments)
           }
         }
       }
       
       function GetCurrentDateTime(date) {return +date}
       
       $("#txtmessage").keypress(function (e) {
            console.log();
            var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (e.which == 13) {
                $('#btnSendMsg').click();
            }
        });


        $('#btnSendMsg').click(function () {

            var msg = $("#txtmessage").val();
            if (msg.length > 0) {

                var userName = $('#hdUserName').val();

                var date = GetCurrentDateTime(new Date());

                chatHub.server.sendMessageToAll(userName, msg, date);
                $("#txtmessage").val('');


            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSendMsg">send</button>

<input type="hdUserName" placeholder="User name" value="foo" />
<input type="text" id="txtmessage" placeholder="Text message" />
```

Comment: i have it like this       <asp:TextBox ID="txtmessage" runat="server" Height="49px" Width="214px"></asp:TextBox>  <div class="input-group" style="float: right;">
                                <input class="form-control" style="visibility: hidden;" />
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" id="btnSendMsg" value="enviar" />

Comment: ASP prefix suggests this is server side code, what is the output on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You shold copy :

```
$("#txtmessage").keypress(function (e) {
            console.log();
            var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (e.which == 13) {

                var msg = $("#txtmessage").val();
                if (msg.length > 0) {
                var userName = $('#hdUserName').val();
                var date = GetCurrentDateTime(new Date());
                chatHub.server.sendMessageToAll(userName, msg, date);
                $("#txtmessage").val('');

            }
        });
```

or create some send function :')